# Good book on the standard model for theoretical mathematicians

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

I am a mathematician who specialises in algebraic geometry and algebraic topology. I am looking for a good textbook on the standard model that gears towards readers with more of a math rather than a physics background. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to be able to calculate anything? Do you want to know the buzzwords physicists use? Do you want to know the buzzwords mathematicians use to describe what physicists do?

Comment: My goal is to understand the standard model: The structure of ideas behind it, the structure of ideas behind it, the mathematical formulae, and yes, ultimately calculations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/312/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/114415/2451 and links therein.